# How to find a mathematical way to see if a dependency exists between certain rows in a dataframe in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, statistics

I have a dataframe where the name of tests our team developed are in rows and the parts that went through that test as columns with values being either "1"(pass) or "0" fail.

When i encode the columns to make one long hex pattern, i see certain tests failing same parts. How can i take the information i have in dataframe and use some kind of probability or variance approach or any other mathematical approach to prove that the tests that have same failing parts are due to dependency between tests and not due to co-incidence.

```
enter code here

data = {'part1':[1, 1, 1, 1],
        'part2':[1, 0, 1, 0],
        'part3':[0, 1, 0, 1],
        'part4':[0, 0, 0, 0],
        'hex_string':["0xC", "0xA","0xC","0xA"]}

# Creates pandas DataFrame.
df = pd.DataFrame(data, index =['test1',
                            'test2',
                            'test3',
                            'test4'])
```

In the above example you can see that test1 and 3 have same device failing or passing and same can be said for test2 and 4. How can i confirm what i see visually using math to prove that the failing and passing parts are not co-incidence

Please let me know if you need more info than this, my original dataframe that i cannot share can be as small as 100 (tests) * 500 (parts) or can be as big as 20,000(tests) * 500 (parts).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your data has a fixed length (N) for each test, you can simply use `cosine_similarity` to do what you desire. in this approach, you're considering each test as a binary vector in N-dimensional space (N is the number of parts).

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity
data = {'part1':[1, 1, 1, 1],
        'part2':[1, 0, 1, 0],
        'part3':[0, 1, 0, 1],
        'part4':[0, 0, 0, 0],
        'hex_string':["0xC", "0xA","0xC","0xA"]}

# Creates pandas DataFrame.
df = pd.DataFrame(data, index =['test1',
                            'test2',
                            'test3',
                            'test4'])
cosine_similarity(df.iloc[:, :-1])
```

output:

```
array([[1. , 0.5, 1. , 0.5],
       [0.5, 1. , 0.5, 1. ],
       [1. , 0.5, 1. , 0.5],
       [0.5, 1. , 0.5, 1. ]]) # rows and columns are the tests
```

As we can see the cosign similarity can be considered as a good measurement for tests dependencies, this would be more intuitive as your dataframe gets bigger!

Comment: thanks for introducing me to cosine similarity, let me look into it more and see if that would be an acceptable solution

Comment: hi @meti, cosine similairty leads to issues when  i have all "0"'s in rows and jaccard similarity works a lot better. My question next would be how can i implement the other two similarity co-efficients such as simple matching co-efficient and tanimoto co-efficient